# php github webhook not executed on server

Tags: php

I am trying to push changes to server with github webhook, with the following php script:

```
<?php
    shell_exec("cd /var/www/repo.io/ && git pull");

?>
```

Push is detected on github, but no action is being triggered on server. Also, I got no permission or any other kind of error on the server. So, php script is not executed at all from the web.
But when I am inside server, through CLI - it works.
What can be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: _Assuming_ the hook has been setup correctly, it's probably permissions or paths - use `exec` and look at [the output variable](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php) to read the error message (assuming there is one) that the current shell_exec call is triggering. Then action accordingly (or if you can't action it - _put it in the question_).

Comment: no error messages, everything failed silently.

Comment: `shell_exec` doesn't redirect the error stream. Test your code using the following: `<?php echo shell_exec('cd /var/www/repo.io/ && git pull 2>&1');`. Try simply navigating to the page using your web browser and look at the returned output.